# Conditional indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing, conditional-statements

As a working example :
a data frame df consists of two numerical columns: x, y I wish to index the value in column y based on the max value in column x

```
x<-rnorm(100,1, 2)
y<-rnorm(100,0.5, 2)

df<-data.frame(x,y)
max(x)
#[1] 5.842416
```

how to identify the value of (y) based on the row position of (x) in the data frame and not based on the value of (x)?

The code is implemented in a for loop and this is my solution using dplyr however it returns a column of NAs without errors

```
x[i] <- max(df$x)
y[i]<-df %>% group_by(y) %>% slice(which.max(x[i]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you have to do is filter the data frame by x and then pull out the value(s) in y, as shown below:

```
set.seed(2021)
x <- rnorm(100,1, 2)
y <- rnorm(100,0.5, 2)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

df[df$x == max(df$x), "y"]
#> -1.398957
```

If you insist on using the tidyverse:

```
df %>% 
  filter(x == max(x)) %>% 
  pull(y)
#> -1.398957
```

If you don't need a data frame, you can try:

```
y[x == max(x)]
#> -1.398957
```

The key to this is logical subsetting--the stuff R is good at!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df[which(df$x == max(df$x)), "y"]
```